# How can I display parameter from PHP to jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Using `success: function(data)` in the jquery code, when I retrieve the data from PHP, I can't display the parameter `str"=>$dataString` in the jQuery code.

```
success: function(data) {
    alert(data[0]);
    $("#display").html(data[str]);
}
```

ajax.php:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['dataString'])) {
    $dataString=$_POST['dataString'];
    echo (array("str"=>$dataString));
  } else {$_POST['dataString']="";}
?>

    <html>
    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./public/stylesheets/stylesheets.css"  >
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./public/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var dataString;
      $("#valueforajax").blur(function() {
        dataString = $.trim(this.value);
        if (dataString){
        // until here it works
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'html',
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: 'dataString=' + dataString,
            //{"dataString": dataString}
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
              alert(data[0]);
              $("#display").html(data[str]);
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
  <title>mange panel</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <br>Type value for test in ajax<input id="valueforajax" type=text name='ajaxtest'>
    <div id="display">show</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The response from your AJAX call will, I suspect, contain the word `Array` followed by the HTML of your page. If you want to pass the array back to your JavaScript as an array, you'll probably need to use something like `json_encode(array("str"=>$dataString));` and then suppress the HTML output.

Comment: why hv you put both php and html code in the same file. You should put separate them in two files else you need to detect for ajax request to page.

Comment: yes i add 'json_encode' but what I need to change in my jquery code to display the array ?

Comment: becose the code work but it cano't enter to the line 'success: function(data)' so I just want to see what the problem Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax.php

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['dataString'])) {
     echo $_POST['dataString'];
     exit(0);  //this will supress html output
  }
  else {
   //do nothing
  }
?>
```

---

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'html',
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: 'dataString=' + dataString, //{"dataString": dataString}
    cache: false,
    success: function(data)
    {
       alert(data);
       $("#display").html(data);
       }
    });
```

Comment: we are close. i got on html page `Type value for test in ajax
{"str":"453"} 
Type value for test in ajax
show`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want to return the php array to Jquery and work with it there?

If so json_encode the array in php then return it to javascript, you should be able to work with it then.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the response from the server should be a json string or just a string.

```
<?php
   if (isset($_POST['dataString'])) {
     $dataString=$_POST['dataString'];
     echo json_encode(array("str"=>$dataString));
     exit(0);
    }
     else {
        echo json_encode(array("str"=>""));
        exit(0); //you don't want rest of html in respose too.
    }

?>
```

And in success

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert( obj.str);
```

Comment: yes i add 'json_encode' but what I need to change in my jquery code to display the array ?